# Конкурсный вопрос не сразу отображается в списке категории

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

Опубликовал несколько дней назад вопрос [Запись png картинки без использования java.awt.image.BufferedImage](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593599/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-png-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-java-awt-image-bufferedimage)

Сегодня объявил конкурс.
В общем списке конкурсов вопрос отображается.
При выборе метки **java** - вопроса нет в списке конкурсных.

Comment: Да не, вроде все норм http://s020.radikal.ru/i722/1611/ae/02e6e3120130.jpg ... может он не учитывает конкретно вас, ведь вопрос ваш?

Comment: у меня тож норм

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, проблема все еще присутствует?

Comment: Если вы смотрели сразу после объявления конкурса, то могла быть задержка кэша.

Comment: Проверил, действительно есть задержка в 1-2 минуты.

Comment: Вопрос отображается. Всем спасибо.